# Sqoop custom PasswordLoader

Tags: classpath, sqoop

I am trying to create a custom PasswordLoader
I created a class:

```
package custom.password.loader 
class CustomPasswordLoader extends FilePasswordLoader {
   override def loadPassword(p: String, conf: Configuration): String = ???
}
```

calling the following sqoop call:

```
sqoop export -libjars /path/to/jar/the.jar -Dorg.apache.sqoop.credentials.loader.class=custom.password.loader.CustomPasswordLoader --password-file some_file ...
```

I get:

```
java.io.IOException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
```

Meaning sqoop couldn't find this class on class path. how could I add this to jar to sqoop classpath without installing it in `$SQOOP_HOME/lib`

Sqoop version: 1.4.6-cdh5.12.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since PasswordLoader is needed at the actual sqoop call classpath it have to be at `$SQQOP_HOME/lib`

`-libjar` and `--files` are arguments that pass to the underlying MR job.